# Block subdirectories in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

My site has profiles, and then pages beyond those profiles. (Example: http://www.site.com/profile, http://www.site.com/profile/settings)

I would like to block Google crawlers from the sub folders. I want google to index the /profile/ but not anything beyond it.

Another example: - http://twitter.com/bmull <-- Allow - http://twitter.com/bmull/favorites <-- Block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />` in the pages you dont want to robots to index/follow, however always remember that everything in these files is voluntary and the robots can choose not to follow so I recommend ip or user agent blocking as a better route.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with Google, but isn't guaranteed to work with other spiders.  As secretformula suggested, your best bet is to go with ip or user agent blocking in your server side logic

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/settings
```